# Swift - Using autoLayout on custom Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to center horitzonally a button into my custom cell but I can't.
The constraits are OK but doesn't work...

Some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT1**

I'm cheking the TableView, View and the Cell with:

```
println("TableView width: \(self.tableView.frame.width)")
println("View width \(self.view.frame.width)")
println("Cell width: \(cell.frame.width)")

TableView width: 600.0
View width 375.0
Cell width: 600.0
Cell width: 600.0
```

TableView and Cell are longer than the view. I think that this is the problem. Why isn't my cell fitting to the width screen?

Comment: Can you show the actual constraints that were made?

Comment: Where are those numbers on the left side coming from? They're on the screenshot but not in your interface builder screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the tableView is wider than the window. Try adding top, bottom, left and right constraints to the tableView.

[image]

If this is not the case, please give some more information about the constraints you added and the way you added the number label at the left of the cells.